# Check markup of DIV for html entity

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if a `DIV` contains the HTML entity `&#9660`. How can I do this?

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8r5Py/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a roundabout way, but you could:

```
$('div:contains('+$("<div/>").html('&#9660').text()+')').length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8r5Py/1/

Another demo:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':contains('+$("<div/>").html('&#9660').text()+')')) {
        console.log('Has entity: ' + $this.text());
    } else {
        console.log('Does not have entity: ' + $this.text());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8r5Py/2/

Comment: Thanks! How can I use the `contains` selector with `$(this)`?

Comment: [`$.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is actually meant for this very thing. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8r5Py/2/

Comment: Looks like it only works when I use ▼, not the HTML code for the character. Not a problem, just an observation.

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfidddle.net? My example above does use the html entity, so I'm puzzled.